# What are the different ways to call methods dynamically in java

Tags: java, methods, reflection, invoke

Interface:

```
interface A
{
   void run(String methName);
}
```

Classs:

```
class X implements A
{
    void run(String methName)
    {

    }
    void m1()
    {

    }
    void m2()
    {
    }
    void m3()
    {

    }
```

}

I want to invoke m1, m2  and m3 methods by name dynamically from run method without using reflection mechanism

Comment: Just call them...?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "dynamically" and why reflection is not an option.

Comment: dynamically in the sense we are passing method name as parameter,

Comment: You forget to say  why reflection is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Don't overthink it:

```
switch (methName) {
  case "m1": m1(); break;
  case "m2": m2(); break;
  case "m3": m3(); break;
  default: throw new AssertionError();
}
```

If you want to do something a bit safer, you can define a strategy enum, something like:

```
enum Strategy {
  M1 { @Override public void run(X instance) { instance.m1(); } },
  M2 { @Override public void run(X instance) { instance.m2(); } },
  M3 { @Override public void run(X instance) { instance.m3(); } };

  public abstract void run(X instance);
}
```

then

```
 void run(Strategy strategy) {
   strategy.run(this);
 }
```

Now you can't pass in an arbitrary method name, but are limited to an instance of `Strategy`.

Comment: I only notice this now, but calling it "meth" is... an interesting decision

Comment: here we are hard coding but if we have 20 methods then what we will do?

Comment: Copy and paste those lines 20 times and move on with your life :)

Comment: Or use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful),

> **Reflection** is a language's ability to inspect and dynamically call classes, methods, attributes, etc. at runtime.

So saying that you want to perform reflection without reflection makes no sense.